# Flash AS3 ComboBox style not used

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, combobox, styles

I have a ComboBox (call it cb) on the stage at the first frame. I would like to set it's style to the textfield aligned to right. At start some other component's event first disables and after a while re-enables the ComboBox.

I use the following code to set the style (on the first frame):

```
var menuTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
menuTextFormat.align = "right";
cb.textField.setStyle("textFormat", menuTextFormat);
cb.setStyle("textFormat", menuTextFormat);
cb.setStyle("disabledTextFormat", menuTextFormat);
video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.ON_CHANGE, function (event) {cb.enabled = okButton.enabled = false;})
video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.ON_READY, function (event) {cb.enabled = okButton.enabled = true; })
```

The video is a simple component which dispatches ON_CHANGE event when the camera is initializing and ON_READY when the camera is attached. After that code, i give the cb a new DataProvider and attach a camera to the video component which dispatches the event.

When the flash starts, the style is not active, the text is left aligned. When the first event occures the ComboBox goes to disabled. Still left aligned. After that the second event enables it and the styles applied, it is right aligned.

I want it to right aligned from the first time. I tried to disable/enable the component from AS, but not worked, it seems that need a little time to apply the style.

I also checked that the style is set, i had wrote a timer and traced the alignment, but it said right, so the style is there just not used.

I tried to manually add the component with addChild from AS, but still no success.

How can i force it to use the style?

Thanks for any idea!

Environment:

```
CS5.5
AS3
Flash version: 11.1.102.55
OS: Win XP
```

**Update:**
I figured out how to make a simple concept:

On the stage i drop a ComboBox (instance name cb) and a symbol from library named foobar ( instance name video). On the first frame write the following code:

```
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import fl.controls.ComboBox;

var menuTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
menuTextFormat.align = "right";
cb.textField.setStyle("textFormat", menuTextFormat);
cb.setStyle("textFormat", menuTextFormat);
cb.setStyle("disabledTextFormat", menuTextFormat);

video.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, function (event) {cb.enabled = false;})
video.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event) {cb.enabled = true; })

var arr:Array = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<10 ; i++)
    arr.push({label:"asdfasdf", data:i})
cb.dataProvider = new DataProvider(arr);

video.start()
```

After that, create foobar.as and write the following:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;


    public class foobar extends MovieClip {     
        private var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000);

        public function start() {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.ACTIVATE))
            myTimer.addEventListener("timer", timerHandler);
                        myTimer.start();
        }

        public function timerHandler(evt:Event) {
            myTimer.stop()
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When the first event occures the ComboBox goes to disabled, write       menuTextFormat.align = "right";

Comment: Not worked, but thanks for the advice! The wierd thing, that after the first disable/enable events, it is right aligned at all following events, so it seems that just only the first time it not uses the style.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show that how you are enabling and disabling the combo box because i am creating an example and it works fine for me.

Comment: i add the code at the question, instead of here

Comment: @Swati-Singh i updated with a working concept code which triggers the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply all these styles after the ComboBox is "ready" (which it may not be immediately).

wrap all your text formatting stuff in a function and call the function when the ComboBox fires it's ADDED_TO_STAGE event, and see if that helps...

```
 cb.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, applyMyStyle);


    function applyMyStyle(evt:Event){
       //apply style here to evt.target
    }
```

Not sure if this will help, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I tried that too, but it did not work either. Of course i pay attention to that if it is on the stage it will not trigger ADDED_TO_STAGE, because it will run before the addEventListener, so i tried to add the component from AS. The style is wrong in that way too. Thanks for the tip!